# Decrementing a loop counter as loop is executing

Tags: for-loop, lua, counter

I'm trying to decrement the counter of a for loop as the loop is running. Unfortunately, Lua doesn't seem to allow that. This piece of code should run forever:

```
for i = 1, 100 do
    print (i)
    i = i - 1
end
```

but it does, in fact, simply print the series 1-100. Is that by design? If so, how do I decrement the counter of a running loop (for example because the current cycle was disqualified and should run again)?

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Comment: If you want an infinite loop, just use `while true do ... end`

Comment: I don't want an infinite loop. I want to decrement the loop counter under certain conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design. From [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5):

> #### 3.3.5 – For Statement
>
> All three control expressions are evaluated only once, before the loop starts. They must all result in numbers.

So modifying the value of `i` inside the loop won't change how the loop runs.

Comment: How would I go about solving the problem, then? I need to change the way the loop runs while it's executing.

Comment: @Drakestar You can use a `while` loop, or a `repeat` loop.

Comment: The "control expressions" in that quote refers to the bounds of the for-loop - which in this case are just numbers - not to the exit condition. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 10, 1, -1 do
  print(i)
end
```

If you want to step backwards through a table then do:

```
for i = #SomeTable, 1, -1 do
  print(SomeTable[i].someproperty)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yu Hao above linked to the correct manual page, but quoted the wrong part of it.

Here is the correct quote

> ```
>  for v = e1, e2, e3 do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local var, limit, step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
>    if not (var and limit and step) then error() end
>    while (step > 0 and var <= limit) or (step <= 0 and var >= limit) do
>      local v = var
>      block
>      var = var + step
>    end
>  end
> ```
>
> [..]
>
> - `var`, `limit`, and `step` are invisible variables. The names shown here are for explanatory purposes only.

In other words, the variable that's being looped over *(called "`var`" above)* and the variable exposed to the developer *(called "`v`" above)* are different.  There is no way to access the former.